# Perfect magic 4x4 square

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, magic-square

Can you fill a 4x4 grid with every number from 1 to 16, such that every row, every column and every 2x2 sub-grid of numbers sum to the same value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

> ```
>      1 15  2 16
>     14  4 13  3
>      7  9  8 10
>     12  6 11  5
> ```

Notes:

> ```
>      A B C D
>      E F G H
>      I J K L
>      M N O P
> ```

> Must have
>  
>  A+B = G+H = I+J = O+P
>  
>  C+D = E+F = K+L = M+N
>  
>  A+E = J+N = C+G = L+P
>  
>  I+M = B+F = K+O = D+H
>  
>  B+C = J+K = E+H = M+P
>  
>  F+G = N+O = A+D = I+L
>  
>  E+I = G+K = B+N = D+P
>  
>  F+J = H+L = A+M = C+O
>  
>  which are enough constraints to make it manageable by trial and error.

Comment: correct and well done!

Comment: For more information on this topic see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most-perfect_magic_square

Answer (score 1):

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 5 | 12 |
| 8 | 9 | 4 | 13 |
| 3 | 14 | 7 | 10 |
| 15 | 2 | 11 | 6 |

Each 2x2 square should be (largest + smallest) * 4 / 2. In this case that would be 34.

Comment: You forgot the columns, they don't add up properly.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

This one has a kind of rhythm I find cool:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 2 | 15 |
| 14 | 3 | 13 | 4 |
| 12 | 5 | 11 | 6 |
| 7 | 10 | 8 | 9 |

Comment: The central 2x2 appears to sum to 32 only.

Comment: @loopywalt thats correct, my mistake, I forgot to consider this one. It appears that exchanging rows 3 and 4 fixes it. Then it is interesting to note that it gives a solution similar to yours but with columns 2 and 4 exchanged. So it seems there are not plenty of solutions...